# How can I instruct my compiler to use 8 bit bytes instead of 16 bit integers?

Tags: embedded, assembly, attiny, c++, optimization

I have the following code in my microcontroler program:

```
int analogValue = ADCH;        // ADC Data Register

//
// Simple analog comparator. 
// If analogValue lower than threshold then toggle output high,
// Otherwise toggle it low.
//
if ( analogValue > 128 ) {
    PORTB = 0;                 // Port B Data Register
} else {
    PORTB = _BS( outputPin );  // Port B Data Register
}
```

Where:

- ADCH is the register that contains the value from the ADC
- PORTB is a dital output port that toggles an LED

Looking at the resulting assembly code, I noticed that it is doing a 16 bit compare (lines 40-44) where strictly speaking only 8 bits would have been sufficient:

```
40:   90 e0           ldi     r25, 0x00       ; 0
42:   81 38           cpi     r24, 0x81       ; 129
44:   91 05           cpc     r25, r1
46:   14 f0           brlt    .+4             ; 0x4c <__SREG__+0xd>
48:   18 ba           out     0x18, r1        ; PORTB
4a:   f5 cf           rjmp    .-22            ; 0x36 <__CCP__+0x2>
4c:   28 bb           out     0x18, r18       ; PORTB
4e:   f3 cf           rjmp    .-26            ; 0x36 <__CCP__+0x2>
```

I realize I declared analogValue as **int**, which indeed is 16 bit on AVR, but ...

How can I instruct the compiler to use 8 bit comparison? The Arduino IDE allows me to use **byte**, but avr-gcc by default doesn't.

Check [this](http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Simpel_analog_to_PWM_converter_using_ATtiny13) page for the complete program and its disassembled resulting code.

**EDIT1:**

Changing `int` to `char` changes the assembly code to:

```
14:   11 24           eor     r1, r1          ; r1 = 0
3e:   18 ba           out     0x18, r1        ; PORTB
```

Basically skipping the test entirely.

**EDIT2:** (Thnx: Wouter van Ooijen)

Changing `int` to `unsigned char` changes the assembly code to:

```
3c:   85 b1           in      r24, 0x05       ; ADCH
3e:   ...
40:   87 fd           sbrc    r24, 7          ; compare < 128 (well optimized)
42:   02 c0           rjmp    .+4             ; 0x48 <__SREG__+0x9>
44:   18 ba           out     0x18, r1        ; 24
46:   f7 cf           rjmp    .-18            ; 0x36 <__CCP__+0x2>
48:   98 bb           out     0x18, r25       ; 24
4a:   f5 cf           rjmp    .-22            ; 0x36 <__CCP__+0x2>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I actually think a better practice that avoids this architectural ambiguity is to include `<stdint.h>` then use declarative types like:

- uint8_t for unsigned 8-bit integers
- int8_t for signed 8-bit integers
- uint16_t for unsigned 16-bit integers
- uint32_t for unsigned 32-bit integers

and so on...

Comment: This appears to work (checked the assembly code again). Wasn't familiar with these types at all. Where does the `_t` come from?

Comment: _t indicates, conventionally, that its naming a type

Comment: These are standard fixed width integer types, introduced in C99. You may need to #include <stdint.h>. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed_width_integer_types

Comment: +1. I use this to remove any ambiguity and for ultimate portability

Comment: A danger when using such types is that expression types are often non-portable in surprising ways.  For example, on a system where `int` is 16 bits, given `uint32_t flag;`, the statements `flag &= ~0x00004000;` and `flag &= ~0x00010000;` will behave as expected, but `flag &= ~0x00008000;` will behave rather differently.

Answer (score 8):

The more-or-less standard definition of a byte in C is 'unsigned char'.

Comment: Ah the `unsigned` part did the job, `char` on it's own compiles without warnings.

Comment: A famous C 'gotcha' is that the compiler is free to interpret 'char' as either 'signed char' or 'unsiged char', so the effective range of plain 'char' that you can count on is 0..127. Use plain 'char' only for 7-bit ASCII, never for anything else.